# Reviewed wrong version of resume in phone interview, now what?

Tags: interviewing, resume, internship

I just had a phone interview for an internship position. Right off the bat the hiring manager asked me to go over my resume. Unfortunately I realized after working down through the first few items I had my older copy of my resume in front of me. Nothing drastically changed other than swapping out my fast-food job experience for a section titled relevant coursework. Though I couldn't recall on the spot what I had changed so stuck with completing my review.

Though, now I realize I talked about this fast-food work experience even though the hiring manager didn't see that at all, and I also then skipped the relevant coursework section entirely. I'm obviously thinking this position is already a lost cause, but in hopes of possibly salvaging my blunder, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 6):

The main thing to do is learn from this experience and be better prepared next time. Second, don't be afraid to go "off script".

You knew that the hiring manager wouldn't care about a fast food job, so why go over it simply because it's on the paper?

Third, and most important, there's no shame in saying:

> Excuse me for just a second, I seem to have misplaced my copy of my resume.

and go get the correct one.

There's not much you can say at this point that will chance the interviewer's opinion of you. Make sure you send an email thanking the interviewer for their time.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's irrelevant. Though, since I have very minimal work experience (still being in school) it's one position where I held leadership of a team. Ultimately decided to remove it in favor of more pertinent experience. Despite all my preparation, my nerves found an insidious way of infiltrating the mind and preventing logical thinking. Hopefully this will get easier.

Comment: @matt - comes with experience. I used to regard the first interview as "sacrificial" - I knew I would make some nerves related mistakes. Next one was always better, and by the third, I was pretty confident.